# Decoding the web.config httpmodules

Tags: asp.net

I recently started learning about HttpModules and made my first one. I was wondering if someone could explain why some modules in the the web.config include a lot of extra info and others do not.

**example: not much info**

```
<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
```

**example a lot of info**

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

What is a publickeytoken, version, culture. Do I need to do anything special to use those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are part of the assembly's fully qualified name.

Version should be self-explanatory.
Culture is the culture that the assembly was compiled for.
PublicKeyToken is a value that is cryptographically derived from the key used to sign the assembly, or `(null)` if the assembly is unsigned.

For more information, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69.aspx).

Comment: is there any benefit of adding that extra info?

Comment: It makes the assembly resolution more reliable and specific.